# Does float VS int performance on x86 and ARM differ so much?

Tags: c, floating-point, android-ndk, arm, linderdaum

I was wondering how ARM floating point performance on smartphones is compared to x86. For this purpose i wrote the following code:

```
#include "Linderdaum.h"
sEnvironment* Env = NULL;

volatile float af = 1.0f;
volatile float bf = 1.0f;
volatile int a = 1;
volatile int b = 1;

APPLICATION_ENTRY_POINT
{
    Env = new sEnvironment();

    Env->DeployDefaultEnvironment( "", "CommonMedia" );

    double Start = Env->GetSeconds();

    float Sum1 = 0.0f;

    for ( int i = 0; i != 200000000; i++ )    {        Sum1 += af + bf;    }

    double End = Env->GetSeconds();

    Env->Logger->Log( L_DEBUG, LStr::ToStr( Sum1, 4 ) );
    Env->Logger->Log( L_DEBUG, "Float: " + LStr::ToStr( End-Start, 5 ) );

    Start = Env->GetSeconds();

    int Sum2 = 0;

    for ( int i = 0; i != 200000000; i++ )    {       Sum2 += a + b;    }

    End = Env->GetSeconds();

    Env->Logger->Log( L_DEBUG, LStr::ToStr( Sum2, 4 ) );
    Env->Logger->Log( L_DEBUG, "Int: " + LStr::ToStr( End-Start, 5 ) );

    Env->RequestExit();

    APPLICATION_EXIT_POINT( Env );
}

APPLICATION_SHUTDOWN
{}
```

Here are the results for different targets and compilers.

**1. Windows PC on Core i7 920.**

**VS 2008, debug build, Win32/x86**

```
(Main):01:30:11.769   Float: 0.72119
(Main):01:30:12.347   Int: 0.57875
```

`float` is slower than `int`.

**VS 2008, debug build, Win64/x86-64**

```
(Main):01:43:39.468   Float: 0.72247
(Main):01:43:40.040   Int: 0.57212
```

**VS 2008, release build, Win64/x86-64**

```
(Main):01:39:25.844   Float: 0.21671
(Main):01:39:26.060   Int: 0.21511
```

**VS 2008, release build, Win32/x86**

```
(Main):01:33:27.603   Float: 0.70670
(Main):01:33:27.814   Int: 0.21130
```

`int` is gaining the lead.

**2. Samsung Galaxy S smartphone.**

**GCC 4.3.4, armeabi-v7a, -mfpu=vfp -mfloat-abi=softfp -O3**

```
01-27 01:31:01.171 I/LEngine (15364): (Main):01:31:01.177   Float: 6.47994
01-27 01:31:02.257 I/LEngine (15364): (Main):01:31:02.262   Int: 1.08442
```

`float` is seriously slower than `int`.

Let's now change addition to multiplication inside the loops:

```
float Sum1 = 2.0f;

for ( int i = 0; i != 200000000; i++ )
{
    Sum1 *= af * bf;
}
...
int Sum2 = 2;

for ( int i = 0; i != 200000000; i++ )
{
    Sum2 *= a * b;
}
```

**VS 2008, debug build, Win32/x86**

```
(Main):02:00:39.977   Float: 0.87484
(Main):02:00:40.559   Int: 0.58221
```

**VS 2008, debug build, Win64/x86-64**

```
(Main):01:59:27.175   Float: 0.77970
(Main):01:59:27.739   Int: 0.56328
```

**VS 2008, release build, Win32/x86**

```
(Main):02:05:10.413   Float: 0.86724
(Main):02:05:10.631   Int: 0.21741
```

**VS 2008, release build, Win64/x86-64**

```
(Main):02:09:58.355   Float: 0.29311
(Main):02:09:58.571   Int: 0.21595
```

**GCC 4.3.4, armeabi-v7a, -mfpu=vfp -mfloat-abi=softfp -O3**

```
01-27 02:02:20.152 I/LEngine (15809): (Main):02:02:20.156   Float: 6.97402
01-27 02:02:22.765 I/LEngine (15809): (Main):02:02:22.769   Int: 2.61264
```

**The question is:** what am i missing (any compiler options)? Is the floating point math really slower (compared to int) on ARM devices?

Comment: Change the order of tests: int first, float later. then check if its same

Comment: @tuğrul büyükışık: do i need any additional compiler switches?

Comment: No, i meant cpu warmup condition. You are doing tests between int-float separately or in same main?

Comment: @tuğrul büyükışık: in the same main() - I use the code specified above. I changed the order of int/float loops - results remain the same.

Comment: use volatile on your time variables (start, end)

Comment: remove volatile on the a/b af/bf variables and pass them in, you are measuring memory performance here more than floating point performance (naturally you cannot define a/b as constants here the optimizer will remove them and just post the answer).

Comment: examine the disassembly for fixed vs float code.

Comment: @dwelch: i added ``volatile`` exactly to prevent the optimizer from computing the result.

Comment: I know, that is what I said.  What happens to the results if you remove the memory cycles and time the instructions.  Examine the code produced.

Comment: From a hardware perspective be it add or multiply there is more involved in floating point than fixed point.  Both use a fixed point alu (adder, multiplier, etc) the float though has to prepare the value up front and normalize the value on the backend.  Ideally that is a single clock cycle, but not always.  The arm fpu (well, there are more than one) syncronizes on the backend, you can go do other things then come back and ask for the answer, then it stalls until the answer is done if it is not done.  I dont know how x86 fpus work.  Since you are adding a small number it should be very fast.

Comment: Agreed with @dwelch, remove volatile from a/b, af/bf. If you just use the variable after loop that will be enough to keep optimizer removing the calculation.

Comment: if you can add a complete source code for arm with compile switches you use and post the result, I can run it on some other arm core and post the results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see http://github.com/dwelch67/stm32f4d  see the float03 directory

The test compares these two functions fixed vs float

```
.thumb_func
.globl add
add:
    mov r3,#0
loop:
    add r3,r0,r1
    sub r2,#1
    bne loop
    mov r0,r3
    bx lr

.thumb_func
.globl m4add
m4add:
    vmov s0,r0
    vmov s1,r1
m4loop:
    vadd.f32 s2,s0,s1
    sub r2,#1
    bne m4loop
    vmov r0,s2
    bx lr
```

The results are not too surprising, the 0x4E2C time is fixed point and 0x4E2E is float, there are a few extra instructions in the float test function that likely account for the difference:

```
00004E2C                                                                        
00004E2C                                                                        
00004E2E                                                                        
00004E2E                                                                        
00004E2C                                                                        
00004E2E
```

The fpu in the stm32f4 is a limited to single precision version of the vfp found in its big brothers and sisters.  You should be able to perform the above test on any armv7 with vfp hardware.

By having the __aeabi_fadd function linked in and that extra call made each time through the loop, plus the additional timing of memory accesses, possibly conversions outside or inside (vmov) the library function, etc, can add to what you are seeing.  The answer of course is in the disassembly.

Comment: so it is likely that __aeabi_fadd or whatever your gcc is using, has the operands in general purpose registers so in addition the floating point add there are three vmov instructions per operation that you are measuring, so you are trying to compare one instruction add to six: bl, vmov, vmov, vadd, vmov, bx when compared that way no matter how fast the floating point instruction is it will always be slower than the single fixed point instruction.  If you can get the compiler to make a fair comparison without library calls, you will see the speed match.

Comment: to clarify my results, the numbers in hex are number of system clocks (possibly prescaled) for 10000 loops fixed and float.  There is no difference between the fixed point add and floating point add.  There is very clearly several times more instruction overhead the way the OP is using the fpu which will account for a majority of the difference in execution.  an apples vs oranges test, the above is an apples vs apples test.

Answer (score 5):

`-mfloat-abi=softfp` explicitly calls for emulated floating point. Check the specs of your Galaxy, and compile with hardware FP if possible.

Not all ARM CPU's support hardware floating point to begin with. The default settings of NDK's ARMEABI call for emulated FP though - it's supposed to be compatible with FP-less machines. At best, you can do some run-time branching on CPU capabilities.

Comment: No, ``softfp`` allows the generation of code using hardware floating-point instructions, but still uses the soft-float calling conventions. http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Options.html

Comment: using hard floating point though can/may avoid the additional layers of function calls.

Answer (score 5):

@Seva Alekseyev The `-mfloat-abi` flag only controls how floating point values are passed to functions.  Using `softfp` values are pass using normal registers.  Using `hardfp` values are passed using FPU registers. The `-mfloat-abi` flag doen't control which hardware instructions are used.

Basically `softfp` is use to maintain backwards compatibility with devices that do not have a FPU.  Using `softfp` will result is some extra overhead for devices with FPU.

@Sergey K Comparing x86 and ARM is like comparing apples to oranges.  They are two very different platforms.  The primary design goal for ARM is low power not speed.  You could see some performance improvement using `hardfp`.  There is also a 4.6 version of the compiler available. I think your results are plausible considering the architecture differences.

Comment: What are the pitfalls of ``hardfp``?

Comment: Your binary will not run on device that do not have a FPU.  Most of the newer phones have them.

Comment: will it run on any armv7-compatible chip?

Comment: I don't know. Unfortunately the are many variations on chipsets using the armv7 instruction set.  My best guess is NO.

Comment: in this case it is a problem and i cannot use ``hard`` mode.

Comment: You can use `android_getCpuFeatures()` to determine if a FPU is available. Looks like all armv7 do have a FPU. From docs: `ANDROID_CPU_ARM_FEATURE_VFPv3`
Indicates that the device's CPU supports the VFPv3 hardware FPU instruction set extension. Due to the definition of 'armeabi-v7a', this will always be the case if ANDROID_CPU_ARM_FEATURE_ARMv7` is returned.

Answer (score 4):

These results are believable.

The Cortex-A8 core used in the Exynos 3 SoC has an unpipelined VFP implementation.  I don't remember the exact numbers off the top of my head, but my recollection is that throughput for VFP add and multiply is on the order of an op every 8 cycles on that core.

The good news: that's a really old SoC, and newer ARM SoC's have stronger VFP implementations - add, sub, and multiply are fully pipelined, and throughput is much improved.  Also, some (but not all) Cortex-A8 SoCs support NEON, which gives you fully-pipelined single-precision floating-point.

Comment: Good point with NEON.  There is a page on using NEON in the NDK. See: docs/CPU-ARM-NEON.html